# chat application friend list

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

I have 3 MySQL tables namely chat_comments, chat_friends and user_details and I want to display a friend list.

My tables:

```
chat_comments(comment_id,comment,user_id,user_id2,date_added)
chat_friends(user_id,user_id2,approved)
user_details(user_id, mainimage_id, fullname)
```

To do this, I need a query that will return the needed fields (`u.mainimage_id`, `u.fullname`, `b.comment`, `b.user_id`) so I can loop through the list to display a table.

SQL so far (help from @Andriy M):

```
SELECT
cc.comment,
cc.date_added,
u.fullname,
u.mainimage_id 
FROM
user_details u
LEFT JOIN
    chat_comments cc
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT
            user_id,
            MAX(comment_id) AS maxcomment
        FROM chat_comments WHERE user_id=2020 OR user_id2=2020
        GROUP BY user_id
    ) a ON a.user_id = cc.user_id
       AND a.maxcomment = cc.comment_id
ON a.user_id = u.user_id
WHERE u.user_id IN (
SELECT user_id2
FROM chat_friends
WHERE user_id = 2020
  AND approved = 1
)
```

The above query returns the last comment made by the logged-in user's friends in conversation not the last comment between the logged-in user and his/her friend regardless of who made it.

I would like it to return the last comment between the logged-in user and their friend individually regardless of who made it. In the `chat_messages` table, `user_id` is the sender and `user_id2` is the receiver. Hope it makes sense?

Comment: Have you tried using LEFT JOIN at all, instead of INNER?

Comment: I'm sorry but one uncertainty seems to be left (or, perhaps, to have come along due to your edit). When you said it in your comment, I understood you so that you wanted the last messages *from* the friends *to* the logged-in user. It now appears from the edited question that you want the last messages *in the corresponding conversations*, i.e. regardless of whether it was by the user or by the friend. So which is it actually? (It's the repetition of the phrase *‘regardless of who made it’* in your question that changed the meaning to me. Could you perhaps have mistakenly copy-pasted it?)

Answer (score 1):

Like @imm said in a comment, you need to use an outer join. In case of a left join, the `user_details` table should become the left side of the join, the right side being the result of your inner join of `chat_comments` with your `a` derived table. You'll also need to remove the `user_id IN (…)` condition from inside the `a` subselect and re-apply it to the `user_details` table. Here:

```
SELECT
    cc.comment,
    cc.date_added,
    u.fullname,
    u.mainimage_id 
FROM
    user_details u
    LEFT JOIN
        chat_comments cc
        INNER JOIN (
            SELECT
                user_id,
                MAX(comment_id) AS maxcomment
            FROM chat_comments
            GROUP BY user_id
        ) a ON a.user_id = cc.user_id
           AND a.maxcomment = cc.comment_id
    ON a.user_id = u.user_id
WHERE u.user_id IN (
    SELECT user_id2
    FROM chat_friends
    WHERE user_id = 2020
      AND approved = 1
)
;
```

Alternatively, you could use a right join. In this case you would just need to move the `user_id IN (…)` condition, similarly to the LEFT JOIN solution above, and replace the second `INNER JOIN` with `RIGHT JOIN`:

```
SELECT
    cc.comment, cc.date_added, u.fullname, u.mainimage_id 
FROM
    (
        SELECT user_id, MAX(comment_id) AS maxcomment
        FROM chat_comments
        GROUP BY user_id
    ) a
INNER JOIN
    chat_comments cc ON 
        a.user_id = cc.user_id AND
        a.maxcomment = cc.comment_id
RIGHT JOIN
user_details u ON
 a.user_id = u.user_id
WHERE u.user_id IN (select user_id2 from chat_friends where user_id=2020 AND approved=1)
```

Comment: ran a test with both sql queries and they return all users in the user_details table regardless of if we are friends or not.

Comment: @user1502826: I see what I missed. Please have a look at the updated answer.

Comment: both worked like a charm returning the same results with the second slightly faster though on average. excellent. thanks

Comment: the query returns the last comment by loggedin user's friends but i would like it amended to return the last comment btw the loggedin user (eg 2020) and friend individually not the last comment by friend. so the last comment can be by the loggedin user. in the chat_comments table, user_id is the sender of comment and user_id2 is the receiver

Comment: @user1502826: I'll review my answer a bit later. Until then, please consider editing your question to point out the particular requirement you just specified about the last comment. I mean, what you said makes perfect sense but it's not immediately obvious. (Editing the question will also move it temporarily to the first page in the question list, thus drawing more attention to it, and maybe someone will find a good solution sooner than me. But for the best effect, make sure you **also un-accept** my answer, or some people might disregard your question seeing that it's got an accepted answer.)